# php compare file size before uploading

Tags: php, upload, compare, size

I've problem with following code:

```
$target_dir = "images/";
$folder = "folder/";
$target_file = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$target_file_size = filesize($target_dir.$folder.$target_file);
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$file_comp = $_FILES["file"]["size"] - $target_file_size;

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_dir.$folder.$target_file && $file_comp == 0)){
    echo $target_file." already exists.<br>";
}
```

the check never return true even if file already exixts and have same size, I do not why.

Comment: Check your brackets

Comment: apologize for that!!! shame!! Maybe I need break........ Anyway thank's!

Comment: @FrancescoGiunta Did fixing the brackets fix the problem? If so, then post the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Look carefully at your `if`

```
if(
    file_exists(
        $target_dir.$folder.$target_file && $file_comp == 0
    )
)
```

So you're checking for existence of result of `&&` operation.

Proper code is:

```
if(
    file_exists(
        $target_dir.$folder.$target_file
    )
    &&
    $file_comp == 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

the goal was to verify if a file are has been correctly uploaded.
If  an uploading process goes down, often the file has wrong file size, normally minor then normal. So, checking if size of the file uploading is greater or same as file with same name already on the server, can help.

make subtraction between file size is the wrong and complicate way so better and easier to compare the file size directly.

```
$file_to_upload = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$target_file = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$target_file_size = filesize($target_dir.$folder.$target_file);

if (file_exists($target_file) && $_FILES["file"]["size"] == $target_file_size) {
echo $target_file." already exists.<br>";
}
```

Thank's again!